# Adjust Like-Box

Tags: facebook, width, sidebar

We put the like-box on a sidebar of our site. The width must be 172px. The consequence is, that the text "you like this" besides the like button is nearly unvisible and you can only read the first letters. Does anyone know, if we can put this text under the button, and if yes, how we must change the code.

Comment: Why don't you try to use `button_count` layout instead of `standard`

Answer (score 0):

try to use CSS used in it. For example..

```
.pluginButton button
{
white-space: pre-wrap; 
}
.sp_like
{
width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Like Button Before]
[image: Like Button After]
OR 
user different provide which generate code for "Like Button"
e.g [howtoaddlikebutton](http://www.howtoaddlikebutton.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your help! We changed language from de_DE to en_US in the code, because english needs less letters and so the space is enough now. We will learn CSS-white space programming soon for another solution. Great!